# Boxplot with distibution size histogram on top (and median regression)

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn, boxplot

I'm trying to create a grouped boxplot representing multiple distributions with different sizes. These sizes should be shown in a histogram on top.

My current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd

some_x=[1,2,3,7,9,10,11,12,15,18]
x_appearances=[]
data_for_each_x=[]

for i in range(0, len(some_x)):
    rand_int=rnd.randint(10,30)
    data_for_each_x.append([np.random.randn(rand_int)])
    for j in range(0, rand_int):
        x_appearances.append(i)

f, (ax_hist, ax_box) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)})
ax_hist=sns.distplot(x_appearances, kde=False, hist_kws=dict(alpha=0.7), ax=ax_hist, bins=len(some_x))
ax_box = sns.boxplot(data=data_for_each_x, showfliers=False)
plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0], some_x)

plt.show()
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1fUQ.png)

Now, this is almost what I want. However, the x axis ticks of the histogram do not match the ticks of the boxplot.

Also, it would be great, if there was a way to include a higher-order (let's say order 3) regression curve of the medians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you had one less number of bin than the number of boxes. To rectify it, you have to add 1 to the number of bins and then subtract 0.5 to align them (centered bars) over the boxes of the box plot.

Now I use `arange` to create bins and then center them.

```
f, (ax_hist, ax_box) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)})
ax_hist=sns.distplot(x_appearances, kde=False, hist_kws=dict(alpha=0.7), ax=ax_hist, bins=np.arange(len(some_x)+1)-0.5)
ax_box = sns.boxplot(data=data_for_each_x, showfliers=False)
plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0], some_x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solves it. But for my own data (which is too much to post here), the histogram is always one tick off to the right for some reason.

Comment: Try removing +1 or -0.5 and see how the alignment is varying

Comment: The -0.5 centers the bars of the histogram, which is nice. Changing or removing the +1 does not seem to have any effect. Also unlike the random data, my own data was one off in the histogram from the beginning.

Comment: @Marcel: Glad that you found the issue and my answer helped.

Comment: Well, you solved the problem I was asking for! Still need to figure out what's wrong with my real data. And concerning a regression for the medians, that I also asked for, I will probably open a new thread on how to do that if I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: Yes perhaps opening new question is the best idea

Comment: I found out what's wrong when using my data. For some reason, the histogram on top does not show only bars for the values on the x axis, but rather, it will show bars (or rather no bars) for 0, and other numbers that are not on the x axis. Creating a bar chart instead of a histogram should solve it in my case.